# WPF Change fontSize of button with style fails?

Tags: wpf, styles

Well i have my file Styles.xaml thats merged in the Application.xaml so it applies to every thing..

here are my styles

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Control}" x:Key="baseStyle">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Verdana"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource baseStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2,0,2,0"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="50"/>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Verdana"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
</Style>
```

When im in the editor this seems to work but when i run the application the font-size of the buttons are shrinked to their normal sizes..

My guess is that the buttons create a TextBlock when their content is set to a string and then use the textblock style.. but how can i override this?

Answer (score 9):

You're right about

> My guess is that the buttons create a
>   TextBlock when their content is set to
>   a string and then use the textblock
>   style

. See [this](http://www.go4answers.com/Example/textbloxk-style-override-label-style-73551.aspx) post.

> A workaround is to define a
>   DataTemplate for System.String, where
>   we can explicitly use a default
>   TextBlock to display the content. You
>   can place that DataTemplate in the
>   same dictionary you define the
>   TextBlock style so that this
>   DataTemplate will be applied  to
>   whatever ContentPresenter effected by
>   your style.

So adding the DataTemplate at the end to Styles.xaml will fix the problem

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Control}" x:Key="baseStyle">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Verdana"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource baseStyle}">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2,0,2,0"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="50"/>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Verdana"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24"/>
    </Style>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:String}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}">
            <TextBlock.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}"/>
            </TextBlock.Resources>
        </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

This will keep your Style for a TextBlock but the TextBlock created in a Button for example won't be effected by it

Comment: I wish I could up vote this more times. I spent hours with another developer trying to figure this out. Thanks!

Comment: Are there any "gotchas" with this workaround? For example, if you want styles to apply only to TextBlocks on Butttons and not all other TextBlocks?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your styles, and it works well. So your styles are not the problem. I think it's the place you merged the style as you wrote. You'd better put your ResourceDictionary Styles.xaml in your MainWindow file instead of your Application.xaml.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock>TTT</TextBlock>
        <Button>BBB</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

But your problem remains unclear, if it's not the solution could you clarify a bit more the way you use your styles by posting this part of your code?